# CSS class naming different?

Tags: html, css, class

I am working with the TN3 gallery (jquery slide show) and tried to change a class name to one that I found easier to understand. Thing is the class name that is within the div is different than the class name that controls it in the .css file? I am confused as I have never seen this before? I have only ever named a div class the same name as the class in my css code? Example is here:

```
<div class="tn3 description">

and in the .css file the class that controls this div is:

.tn3-image-description{Code here}
```

So my question is how can a differently named class work???
For me I understand the following:

```
<div class="description">
.description{Code here}
```

Interesting and I am keen to understand how this works as I have not seen things done this way before!

Comment: How do you know that it works?

Comment: Maybe the class gets _replaced_ with `tn3-image-description` by the script dynamically …?

Comment: You sure there's not some generic selector in action declared elsewhere? Like `.someparent > div` to grab the first child div? As you describe it, that would not work.

Comment: @Explosion Pills I know it works because I changed the css as a test. It is definitely linked somewhere somehow?

Comment: @CBroe that is what I was thinking, that perhaps it is being done behind the scenes with jQuery?

Comment: @Kai Qing Sure yes. There are no > pointing to a child elements. The code is exactly as I wrote it above. I should not work no I agree! But it does??? I am thinking that it must be something within the jQuery?

Answer (score 1):

This div is using multiple (2) separate classes: `tn3` and `description`.

Also check if any of the other CSS files are imported in the original css. This is usually done with `@import url("another.css");` syntax, so you can search for `@import` statements.

Comment: I checked out about this using 2 separate classes and yes it appears to be doing that. Thing is the other class is on another sheet that is not in the header tag! The sheet must be linking to this 2nd external stylesheet somewhere else? The set up is not straight forward at all. I did not know it was possible to bring in an external sheet without a link in the head tag of the page! I will dig deeper as there is also XML content. Not sure exactly why this has such a confusing set up!

Comment: You can import one css file from another like this: `@import url("another.css");` Updated answer with this info.

Answer (score 1):

## Classes Are Only Conditions

```
<div class="a b"></div>

<style> 
    .a {color:blue;} /*The style only need to match a element with class "a"*/
    .a.b {color:red;}  /*The style need to match a element with class "a" AND "b"*/
</style>
```

Turns out that `.a.b` has overwritten `.a` and the `div`'s text is in red.

## e.g. no.2

```
<div>
    <div class="c x"></div>
    <div class="c"></div>
    <div class="x"></div>
</div>
```

using `.c.x {}` will only style `"c x"`